# Command not found but ./command works

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to execute hadoop command from bin folder of hadoop. It doesn't work. But ./hadoop in bin folder works. What would be the problem?

Thanks,
Madhu

Comment: would like to see your command and the output being returned

Comment: please add the result of `echo $PATH` and when you're in Hadoop's bin folder, `pwd`.  I suspect Hadoop's bin folder is just not in your path (contrary to Windows, Unix/Linux will *not* just execute files in pwd, unless instructed so (but adding `.` to your path is not really a good solution).

Comment: Even inside bin folder, I am able to execute hadoop command with ./hadoop but not with hadoop command.

Comment: @MadhumithaB please reread my comment: `Unix/Linux will not just execute files in pwd, unless instructed so (but adding . to your path is not really a good solution)` which explains your observation - it's normal behavior.